# Does iOS have a standard way to enter and store a street address?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, street-address

I'd like to prompt for a street address, in exactly the same way as the Contacts app.

I could mimic its UI, but that would involve duplicating a lot of existing functionality; the country list, the way it re-configures based on the country selection, validation, formatting, localization, etc.  Is there an existing framework that provides this?

I'm also storing the entered value in Core Data, which of course doesn't have an Address type.  Is it preferable to store the fields individually, use Transformable, or just use a plain string?  Is there an existing class that I could re-use/subclass for this?

I can assume that iOS 5 is required.

Comment: I'm afraid not. This ui control represents a custom cell in table view. So you have need to creating yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesn't, unfortunately. There are a few projects that help with this, though. You might find my project QuickDialog useful for this: [QuickDialog](http://github.com/escoz/quickdialog)

Answer (score 0):

This is as good as I know of, but may not meet your needs.  From [The Address Book Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/UI_Controllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH5-SW1):

The Address Book UI framework provides four controllers:

ABPeoplePickerNavigationController prompts the user to select a person record from their address book.
ABPersonViewController displays a person record to the user and optionally allows editing.
**ABNewPersonViewController prompts the user create a new person record.**
ABUnknownPersonViewController prompts the user to complete a partial person record, optionally allows them to add it to the address book.